# navigator.clipboard.writeText и https(http)

Tags: javascript, html

указании код копирование работает на https но не работает на http.
Можете помочь?

```js
$('#button1').on('click', () => {
   let text = $('#options_value').html();
   navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
});
```

Comment: Можем. Используй https. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard «This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS)»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в сертификате. Можно его подменить, насколько я знаю.
почему бы не сделать себе сертификат Let's Encrypt (он бесплатный) и не мучаться с http больше?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]